# Custom and unique field for ApplicationUser

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am creating a register form on my application. I have a field that must be unique and have created a custom validation to ensure this. When I submit the form with unique values the page does not change or submit anything. So far my ViewModel looks like this

```
    public class RegisterViewModel
 {
    [Required]
    [CustomValidation(AccountController, "checkifusernametaken", ErrorMessage = "In use already")]
    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    [MaxLength(15, ErrorMessage = "This field must be less than 15 characters in length"), MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "This field must have a value greater than 2")]
    public string UserNameIdentity { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [MaxLength(15, ErrorMessage = "This field must be less than 15 characters in length"), MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "This field must have a value greater than 2")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller I have my custom validation like so:

```
    public JsonResult UserNameInUse(string usernameIn)
    {
        return Json(!context.Users.Any(u => u.UserNameIdentity == usernameIn), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And my asynchronous register method in the same controller:

```
        // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserNameIdentity = model.UserNameIdentity,
                UserName = model.Email,
                Email = model.Email,
                FirstName = model.FirstName
            };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);


            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                // add registering users to the default user role
                UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "User");

                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }



@model Project.RegisterViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserNameIdentity, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserNameIdentity, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" />
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Your model is null when it reaches the controller? Please post the view code as well.

Comment: As soon as I remove the custom validation it works fine, Leaving the register controller open to accepting matching usernameIdentity values from different users. The model isnt empty when it reaches the controller. I'll post view code now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom `ValidationAttribute` that will check the inputed username:

```
public class UniqueUsernameAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        // Get the object
        var username = value as string;

        // Check if exists
        DbContext context = new DbContext();
        var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserNameIdentity == username)

        if (user == null)
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        else
            return new ValidationResult("Username already exists");
    }
}
```

Then you can use it:

```
[Required]
[UniqueUsernameAttribute]
[Display(Name = "Username")]
[MaxLength(15, ErrorMessage = "This field must be less than 15 characters in length"), MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "This field must have a value greater than 2")]
public string UserNameIdentity { get; set; }
```

Comment: perfect, was just creating this extension class as I got your answer